# How to fix warning when labeling files?

Tags: perforce

I don't use perforce a lot.

I am trying to label a file

p4 tag -l ver1 c:\test\main.cpp#head

1 warning reported
    c:\test\main.cpp#head - label in sync.

But I am getting this warning and googling doesn't seem to provide any answers.

What is the reason for getting this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really an error, it's just letting you know that the label already contains the thing that you're trying to label.  It's only a matter for concern if you had reason to believe that was not the case (i.e. you thought this was a new label, or you thought the file had been changed since the label was last updated).

Comment: To verify the contents of label "ver1", you can run 'p4 files //...@ver1', and look at the results. This will help you understand what files are currently described by the ver1 label.

Comment: In order to verify the files I had to checkout files with that label. I wish there was a another way to do that.

Comment: You should not need to either sync or open the files in the label to do anything with the label -- what do you mean by "verify"?  "p4 files @ver1" will show you the names of the files in the label, "p4 print @ver1" will show you their contents, "p4 verify @ver1" will verify the back-end storage (I suspect this isn't what you were talking about though), etc.